# VPN - DC not available

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, domain-controller

i have setup a site-to-site vpn and the connection works sofar ( i can ping and rdp to the DC's IP ). But i can not join the domain because it is not available.

Nslookup says "Can't find server name". Although i have setup rDNS with A/R for subnets 192.168.3.* and 192.168.150.*.

Here is the setup:

**DC Server**

Windows IP Configuration

```
    Hostname. . . . . . . . . . . . . : server
    Primary DNS Suffix  . . . . . . . : company.local
    Ip Routing Enabled  . . . . . . . : Nein
    WINS Proxy Enabled  . . . . . . . : Nein
    DNS Suffix Search List .  . . . . : company.local
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix    :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
    Physical Adress       . . . . . . : xx-30-05-xx-C6-xx
    Dhcp Enabled  . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP-Adress . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.150.152
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    IP-Adress . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.254
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.251
                                        192.168.150.150 (VPN-Router 1)
    DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.254
                                        192.168.150.150
    Primary  WINS-Server  . . . . . . : 192.168.3.254
```

**Remote Network PC**:

Windows IP Configuration

```
    Hostname. . . . . . . . . . . . . : PC1
    Primary DNS Suffix  . . . . . . . : company.local
    Ip Routing Enabled  . . . . . . . : Nein
    WINS Proxy Enabled  . . . . . . . : Nein
    DNS Suffix Search List .  . . . . : company.local
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix    :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : SiS 900-Based PCI Fast
    Physical Adress       . . . . . . : xx-0E-A6-xx-xx-E0
    Dhcp Enabled  . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP-Adress . . . . . . . . . . . . : 164.20.139.145
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 164.20.139.140 (VPN-Router 2)
    DNS-Server. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.150.152
                                        164.20.139.140
```

Any tips?

Comment: Client should be configured to use (only) your domain DNS server

Comment: Sadly it does not help to have only the DC as the DNS server. Without VPN router as secondary DNS Server they have no internet aswell

Comment: OK, but just as a test, if you configure client to use only domain DNS server, can you join it to the domain?

Comment: Nope does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

So many things can be wrong here.

- Are all the ports required to join a domain open in both firewalls?
- Is the Windows Firewall enabled on the DC?
- If so, is the DC allowing connections from ips outside of the 192.168.150.0/24 subnet?

You can find a list of ports required to join a domain [here](http://richardbalsley.com/ports-required-to-join-a-windows-domain-managing-windows-machines-in-a-dmz-with-sccm).

Comment: Yes the ports are open and the firewall is disabled on the dc. All i get from Nslookup is "Server not found" and "No response from server Server:  unknown"